# Does facebook API allow a website to send notification to non-member?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I may be messing up with some ethics of asking here, and I apologize for that but I have a project in mind and to target new users I have an approach. Please read below, and allow my amateurity some leeway.
Suppose user1 gets on my site and enters the facebook profile URL of user2. Now user2, who has never visited my site, doesnt know of it, doesnt have an accoutn on it or anything, gets a notificatoin on his facebook that user1 has entered his profile url or has involved user2 in osme activity. 
Does the faceabook API allows this? I've a friend who has used facebook GRAPH but he's unsure about this. Can any of you please direct me?
Secondly, if that requires me to create** a facebook app of the website(the app will grab the notification first and then forward it to target's facebook notifications), do facebook apps/developer cert. cost something?

Comment: No, you can not send any kind of notification to users that have not logged in to your app. That would simply be considered spam by most people. And with API v2, having someone enter a Facebook profile URL won’t be of much use to you anyway, since the `username` field was removed from the API, so you can not get any details about that user in any case.

Comment: Then how come I get candycrush and the likes of requests when I've never logged in to apps or even visited their page?

Comment: Because the use _invites_, which are requests players can send to their friends. But those are only available for Game apps on Canvas, and they have nothing to do with manually copying profile URLs either.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. Do you have any other suggestion or say in this? I mean is there any other possibility to achieve what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: What _are_ you trying to achieve here? That whole “user copy&pastes a profile URL” thing doesn’t seem to make much sense to me, what is that supposed to be good for?